# How to convert a 5MB video to 2MB using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to convert a video of any file size x to a specific file size y ??

I have a video test.mp4 which is 5mb i would like to set the size to 2mb

Is it possible to get exact 2mb using ffmpeg

Comment: You need to include some information on the input file. The output of `ffmpeg -i test.mp4` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Use this option:

`-fs limit_size outputfilename`

within your parameters, but use it before the output file's name. The limit_size is normally expressed in bytes. This option sets a hard limit on the size of the output file. Do not set bitrates when using this option, because then the encoding takes the supplied bitrate and simply truncates if it overshoots the limit size.  Also, quality could be affected badly whenever you use hard file size limits.